# cakephp using multiply lookup tables

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

all
I have been learning php and have put together a simple site to track vehicle faults and repairs, but now i am trying to transfer it to cakephp framework to make it easier to work with. My problem is that i have 4 tables,

1. the fault and  repair
2. a list of vehicles
3. a list of symptoms
4. a list of fault codes.

Each repair can have 3 vehicles, 3 symptoms and 3 codes relating to it so i have lookup table to link the fault/repair id to the symptoms, code and vehicles.

i have setup basic code for the vehicle , symptom and fault code models like this:

```
 public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
        'Fault' =>
            array(
                'className' => 'Fault',
                'joinTable' => 'Faults_vehicles',
                'foreignKey' => 'vehicle_id',
                'associationForeignKey' => 'fault_id'
                )  
    );
```

and this lets me search for any faults in the faults table with a given vehicle ID, and this works fine. My problem is how can i set it up so i can do a search for faults in the Faults table with a given vehicle ID and a given symptom ID that have a matching Fault code ID.

I am very new to php and have only just started using cakephp so sorry in advance if this makes no sense at all.

thanks for your time

j

Answer (score 0):

You will need to make your joins manually (See http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#joining-tables ) rather than relying CakePHP's containable or recursive features for this for two reasons:

1. CakePHP's default behavior is for data for models associated by HABTM will be gotten from the database in a separate query from the "parent" model.  This means if you tried to add a condition to your query that involves a column from a model associated by HABTM, you'll get an error about that column doesn't exist in your query.
2. When left to its own devices, CakePHP always uses LEFT joins.  You will need to use INNER joins to do what you want.

I think your find should look something like this, though I'm guessing at what your tables are named, how their schemas look, etc.

```
$this->Fault->recursive = -1;
$this->Fault->find('all', array(
    'contain' => array('Code'),
    'joins' => array(
          array(
              'table' => '(SELECT * FROM vehicles LEFT JOIN 
                     faults_vehicles ON faults_vehicles.vehicle_id = vehicles.id)'
              'alias' => 'Vehicle',
              'type' => 'inner',
              'conditions' => array(
                   'Vehicle.fault_id = Fault.id',
                   'Vehicle.code' => $vehicleCode,
              ),
          ),
          array(
              'table' => '(SELECT * FROM symptoms LEFT JOIN 
                     faults_symptoms ON faults_symptoms.symptom_id = symptoms.id)'
              'alias' => 'Symptom',
              'type' => 'inner',
              'conditions' => array(
                   'Symptom.fault_id = Fault.id',
                   'Symptom.code' => $symptomCode,
              ),
          ),
          array(
              'table' => '(SELECT * FROM codes LEFT JOIN 
                     faults_codes ON faults_codes.code_id = codes.id)'
              'alias' => 'Code',
              'type' => 'inner',
              'conditions' => array(
                   'Code.fault_id = Fault.id',
                   'Code.code' => $faultCode,
              ),
          ),
     ),
));
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much, I have been trying to sort this problem out for some time now. I have changed it a bit and added some if statement so i can search for all faults if no vehicle or symptom is selected. This code works but i would like to no if i could make it any better or do it in a better way.

in my faults controller i call the model like this.

$this->set('searchResults', ClassRegistry::init('fault')->getSearchResults($vehicle, $dtc , $symptom ));

and then my faults model is:

```
function getSearchResults($vehicle, $dtc, $symptom) {

    $VehicleSearch = null;

    $DtcSearch = null;
    $SymptomSearch = null;

    if($symptom != 'ALL'){
        $SymptomSearch = array(
          'table' => '(SELECT * FROM symptoms LEFT JOIN 
                 faults_symptoms ON faults_symptoms.symptom_id = symptoms.id)',
          'alias' => 'Symptom',
          'type' => 'inner',
          'conditions' => array(

               'Symptom.fault_id = Fault.id',
              'Symptom.symptom_id' => $symptom,
          ),
      );
    }


    if($vehicle != 'ALL'){
        $VehicleSearch = array(
          'table' => '(SELECT * FROM vehicles LEFT JOIN 
                 faults_vehicles ON faults_vehicles.vehicle_id = vehicles.id)',
          'alias' => 'Vehicle',
          'type' => 'inner',
          'conditions' => array(

               'Vehicle.fault_id = Fault.id',
              'Vehicle.vehicle_id' => $vehicle,
          ),
      );
    }


    if($dtc != 'ALL'){
        $DtcSearch = array(
          'table' => '(SELECT * FROM dtcs LEFT JOIN 
                 faults_dtcs ON faults_dtcs.dtc_id = dtcs.id)',
          'alias' => 'Dtc',
          'type' => 'inner',
          'conditions' => array(

              'Dtc.fault_id = fault.id',
              'Dtc.dtc_id' => $dtc,
          ),
      );
    }

$this->recursive = -1;
$Results = $this->find('all', array(
'conditions' => array(),

'joins' => array(

    $VehicleSearch,$DtcSearch,$SymptomSearch
      ,       
 ),           
 ));         
return $Results; 
}
```

Many thanks for everyones help.

Jason