# Cakephp Adding To A Database Using Multiple Lookup Tables

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

thanks for any help or advise in advance. I'm new to php and very new to cakephp. I have a database of vehicle faults and linked to the faults DB in lookup tables relating to the dtc code id, symptom and vehicle id. Each fault can have 3 vehicles linked to it, 3 dtc codes and 3 symptoms, so i have 3 lookup tables faults_dtcs, faults_vehicles and faults_symptoms.

If i submit a form with all the information to be added to the DB how would i setup a query so my fault is added to the faults DB and then the new fault.id is added to each lookup table.

hope this makes sense, kinda confused myself writing this.

thanks

Jason

Comment: Sounds like you should start by reading the docs about associations, especially HABTM, and then come back when you any specific questions. **http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#hasandbelongstomany-habtm** | **http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#saving-related-model-data-habtm**

Comment: 1. You should accept someone's answer to your first [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24000942/cakephp-using-multiply-lookup-tables) **OR** clarify your existing question. 2. You should share your database schema, including entity relations. 3. Finally, if you have the database already implemented, use `cake bake` to generate code (at least as a starting point.)